# Jersey filter ContainerRequestContext with HttpServletRequest return nullpointer

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey

I am injecting `HttpServletRequest` to a  `ContainerRequestFilter`. When I am trying to use abort with and I am getting `NullPpointerException`.

```
@Provider
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context  HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext )
                    throws IOException {
       // String auth = requestContext.getHeaderString("authorization");
        UriInfo UriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        System.out.println(UriInfo.getPath());

        //login request 
        if (UriInfo.getPath().equals("resource/users/login")) {
            return ; 
        }

        if (httpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()== true) {
             requestContext.abortWith(Response
                  .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)               
                  .build());
        }
```

Stacktrace

```
    :09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appConfig] in context with path [/vaad2] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at filters.AuthorizationRequestFilter.filter(AuthorizationRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So the `httpRequest` is null? If so, how do you register it? If not, what or what line is the exception pointing to?

Comment: I meant how do you register the filter?

Comment: register(SomeFilter.class); is how I am doing it in my ResourceConfig file